# How decide on best options for adding a store to a Bootstrap Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, e-commerce

I have a new client that needs a site built with both a blog and a store. We are going to use a custom Bootstrap theme with Wordpress CMS.

I am trying to understand my best options for a store and I would like to know what everyone here thinks.

It's very important to me that the store blends nicely with our site. Design and aesthetics are very important, which means that customization is important.

It would be okay if the store was an outside resource to the primary site, but ideally, it would be a part of the same domain.

1. Should I go with WooCommerce? Some kind of Shopify integration?
   Custom built? Something else?
2. For the best option, what are the basic steps to making it work with 
   the scenario I laid out (ie, Wordpress CMS + custom Bootstrap theme)?

> UPDATE #1
>
> So far, I have come up with a few ideas: Bootstrap for front-end design, Wordpress for CMS backend...
>
> - Shopify as an external ecommerce site (ie, a minimalist Shopify store that opens in a new tab from external links on the main site).
> - Building a store front-end with Bootstrap and managing commerce back-end through an alternative solution that integrates fully into our site.
>
> But I am not sure what those "alternate solutions" are or how to approach either doing it myself or finding someone to do it.

Let me know what you all think. Looking forward to hearing back.

Comment: Just customize a theme like this one: https://woocommerce.com/storefront/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working with my designer to decide on the best solution: to build a Wordpress CMS with Foundation, with a WooCommerce store.

I think this makes a lot of sense, but I am still not sure when to decide if a fully-custom store would make sense. I may talk to a developer about this at some point. If there is anyone here who would be willing to discuss in-person, let me know.

Thanks.